# Residuals by group - is it just noise?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, residuals

## Setup

I need to model some event, that actually does not seem to fit a distribution, or maybe a Tweedie, it seems to be a burning cost model. And so I have a prediction made by a GLM. Every observation is one realisation of an individual, and these individuals have observations that are either of group D, or group N.

If I'm correct, the individual selects for each observation if the group should be either D or N.

So it looks like this :

```
| Individual | Group | Observation | Prediction |
|-------------|-------|-------------|------------|
| 1           | D     | 100         | 45         |
| 1           | D     | 0           | 49         |
| ...         | ...   | ...         | ...        |
| 1           | N     | 0           | 100        |
| ...         | ...   | ...         | ...        |
| 2           | D     | 5           | 2          |
| ...         | ...   | ...         | ...        |
```

So thanks to my GLM, I can have the predictions, and hence calculate residuals.

## What do I need?

So the idea is to see if these "raw residuals" are totally distributed as random, or if some individuals truly have something we can't capture with the GLM.

To try to find something, I calculated the residuals per individual (as the sum of observations - sum predictions) for groups D and N, and plot it. It gives something like this :

[image]

It looks like a random cloud, when we look at the first bisector, there is no point, in the upper right area. My understanding of the phenomenon :

The individuals selected for each observation if should be labelled as D or N, and if their residual is superior to 0 (no matter the axis) this observation is a bad choice cause the value is higher than the average.

The other separation line is the bisector, since for positive values, if Y > X then residuals on the D group are higher than on the N group. So it targets better for the N group.

**So my question is:**

Is there a way to say whether or not these points are "random", or can we find a statistical boundary between the middle "random point", and the special observations, where individuals are more accurate?

I thought at something like a confidence interval, but since it's 2D data I don't really know how to handle this. Maybe the residuals should follow a law? I'm not really sure.